# How to run a Java (.jar) in R?

Tags: java, r

Is there any way to run a Java jar file in R? I want one of the outputs of a .jar be used in R.

Comment: You could start by reading through the source code for the [XLConnect Package](https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect).

Comment: Downvoted for not accepting an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `system` to run an operating system command from R.

To run a java jar on a well-configured system, this should work:

```
 system("java -jar /path/to/my.jar")
```

You can add other parameters, for example maybe the Java code takes input from a file which you write with R and pass the filename. Then output from the Java code could be written to files and then read from R. Without knowing what the Java code does we can't be more specific.

It is possible to directly interface with Java code but that requires full knowledge of the internals of the jar so you know what functions to call with what parameters. This is usually referred to as the "API" for that Java.

Otherwise, write a file, call `system`, read a file, is sometimes the simplest way to run code in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

Java's `.jar` can only be run by `java`; so what you need is a way to run an external command from R. The command will be `java`, with arguments `-jar` and `your.jar`.

As far as I can tell, you need to use [system](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) function, something along the lines of

```
javaOutput <- system("/usr/local/bin/java -jar your.jar", intern = TRUE)
```

(note I have not tested that, so please do test)